# How to run a clean up code when a user exits from a windows authentication based ASP.Net MVC web site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 intranet based web application which is using **Windows authentication**. Whenever the user launches the app, we need to store some user specific data in the database (just for the current user session).

I need a full proof way to delete this temporary data from the database when the user exit from the application (i.e. by closing the browser window, due to inactivity for more than 30 minutes, network failure etc.)

I am just thinking of including a javascript in the layout page for recording the user's last activity time in the database at regular intervals and then building a scheduler which can check the database and delete the user's temp data if the activity time is higher than the defined threshold.

Please suggest if there is any better and easier way to do this.

Comment: I think you are confusing the notion of *logging out* and *user closing the browser window/killing the browser process* which is not at all the same thing. The first notion is something that could be detected reliably, the second not.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is definitely cleaning up even after the user closes the window without logging out. We use a similar solution, where we have a scheduled job look for expired sessions and delete relevant data. Our method for finding expired solutions is a little more simplistic, though.

We have an HttpModule that on `AuthenticateRequest`, updates the `LastActiveOn` property of our user entity. We filter out certain types of requests (like AJAX polling, requests to images and static resources, etc.).

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response, so idea is similar i.e check for expired session using a scheduled job and do the cleanup. I was thinking of including a javascript script beacause one page of my app is a dashboard page which gets upaded using Ajax long polling. When this page is open I need to treat that user is still online and looking at the application. If any other page is open and user is inactive then it needs to be treated as inactivity and clean up can be done. I liked this HttpModule solution over javascipt but please suggest how to take care of Dashboard page?

Comment: If your long-polling interval shorter than the interval after which you consider them "inactive" (presumably it is), then all you need to do is just include the long-polling path to the paths that are allowed to update LastActiveOn in the HTTP module.